# How to use win environment variable "pathlib" to save files?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, pathlib

I'm trying to use win environment variable like `%userprofile%\desktop` with `pathlib` to safe files in different users PC.

But I'm not able to make it work, it keep saving in on the running script dir.

```
import pathlib
from datetime import datetime
```

`a = r'%userprofile%\desktop\test2'
b = 'test'
def path(path_name, f_name):
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d%m-%H%M%S")
    file_name = f'{f_name}--{date}.xlsx'
    file_path = pathlib.Path(path_name).joinpath(file_name)
    file_dir = pathlib.Path(path_name)
    try:
        file_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    except OSError as err:
        print(f"Can't create {file_dir}: {err}")
    return file_path

path(a, b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
a = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'\desktop\test2'
# rest of script....
```

Comment: I think the added literal string should be written like this `r'\desktop\test2'`.

Comment: salparadise: OK—did that after I verified it didn't working properly the way you had it.

Comment: If we want the home directory, then use `file_dir = pathlib.Path('~/Desktop/test2').expanduser()` and join it idiomatically as `file_path = file_dir / file_name`. pathlib will change it to use backslash on Windows. That said, Windows doesn't have the fixed Unix convention for the home directory. There are dozens of individually relocatable folders defined for each user. In this case "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" is the default location for [`FOLDERID_Desktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid#FOLDERID_Desktop), but it shouldn't be depended on.

Answer (score 6):

`pathlib` does have [Path.home()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home), which expands to the user's home directory.

```py
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.home())    # On Windows, it outputs: "C:\Users\<username>"

# Build a path to Desktop
desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop"
print(desktop)    # On Windows, it outputs: "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop"
```

Comment: While `pathlib` can handle the user's home directory, it doesn't have anything equivalent to the generic [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) that I am aware of however.

Answer (score 4):

I use `os.path.expandvars`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars

```
import os
os.path.expandvars(r"%UserProfile%\Pictures")
'C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures'
```

Comment: beautiful. just what i was looking for!